# Performance issues with SQL Server SignalR Backplane in ASP.NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#

I have an ASP.NET Framework 4.8 application that uses SignalR. I recently modified the IIS pool to support 10 processes, and when I did that, SignalR stopped working. Upon researching, I found options called "backplanes." Ideally, I would use Azure Service Bus, but my system is not hosted on Azure services, as it's a cloud without Azure Stack support. Consequently, I implemented the SQL Server backplane, but SignalR's performance decreased significantly. I conducted a test by creating a connection string just for the backplane and noticed that it generated over 550 lines in less than a minute after connecting to my hub. Can anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvvT9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/118Sp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybQYI.png)

Note: I cannot use Redis or any other distributed cache option. My question is whether there is any way to optimize the SQL Server backplane.